# PHP MySQL value pass to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

hei,

```
  $i=0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "
        <tr><td>".$row["Number"]."</td><td>".$row["MusikName"]." ".$row["MusikURL"]."</td></tr>";
```

this part works...it give me  -> 1 test1 url1.de  2 test2 url2.de ...

So what I want is to pass the URL to a JavaScript Array...by doing in phpscript

```
    $urlarray[]=$row["MusikURL"];
    echo $urlarray[$i]; // gives me url1.de url2.de url3.de
    i++; // to fill $urlarray[1] [2] [...]  with urls
```

How  do I pass the urls to a JavaScript Array so that I can access to those by
javascriptarrayurl[1] javascriptarrayurl[2] (result should be a clear url) ... I got troubles with JSON :c

thanks in advance !!

Comment: " I got troubles with JSON" - what have you tried with JSON/AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery and have something like

```
<?php
$returnArray = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($returnArray, $row);

}

$jsonArray = json_encode($returnArray);
?>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var objArray = $.parseJSON("<?php echo $jsonArray; ?>");

    for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
        var row = objArray[i];

        console.log(row);

        // Now here you have access to row.Number row.MusikURL
    }
});
```

Comment: @Ray and Barmar I tried it...didn't work...even if I use JSON.parseJSON...  :c http://paste2.org/09C0JY8w here is the code of my project ... (the first php script and the javascript at the bottom is important ...Could you please help me where the mistakes are ? Anyways thanks for help !

Comment: @Ray you can't believe how much helpful you was ...I tried to do this since 1 month ._.  btw. I had also to change it to jQuery I think :c

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_encode()` to convert a PHP variable to its Javascript literal notation.

```
<script>
var urlarray = <?php echo json_encode($urlarray); ?>;
</script>
```